# Proguard obfuscation giving database is locked error

Tags: android, sqlite, obfuscation

I want to publish my android app on PlayStore and before that I am obfuscating my APK using `Proguard`.

Without obfuscating app is working fine without any errors.

But when I create APK with Proguard obfuscation getting following error:

```
09-22 12:29:45.246: E/SQLiteLog(11262): (5) database is locked
09-22 12:29:45.246: E/SQLiteDatabase(11262): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.test.testapp/databases/testapp_db'.
09-22 12:29:45.246: E/SQLiteDatabase(11262): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
09-22 12:29:45.246: E/SQLiteDatabase(11262):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
09-22 12:29:45.246: E/SQLiteDatabase(11262):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
09-22 12:29:45.246: E/SQLiteDatabase(11262):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:627)
09-22 12:29:45.246: E/SQLiteDatabase(11262):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:313)
```

Anyone know why I am getting this error?

I have also tried other proguard options like `-keep class`, `-keepclasseswithmembernames` and `-keep class * implements java.sql.Driver`

Comment: are you using predefined database from assets/web? you can also include source of onCreate method of dbhelper class ... are you using dbhelper singleton?

Comment: but what is the relation between database locked and obfuscation?
I am creating dbhelper class instance multiple times

Comment: problem is not with obfuscation but with optimalization ... any `assumenosideeffects` options in your proguard file?  ... to check if it is optimalization's problem use `dontoptimize` ...

Comment: yes, I have already tried with `dontoptimize`. App will work only with `dontobfuscate` paramenter